# hardie plank siding minimum length

Tags: siding

I'm starting a project to reside my house with hardieplank lap siding.  I have a few corners where the window is very close to the corner.  I plan to use hardie trim around the windows and at the corners.
What is the best way to handle this situation, wide trim pieces or a very short length of hardieplank? 
What is the minimum length of hardieplank I can have between 2 pieces of trim (likely nailed to 1/2 inch plywood sheathing with no stud behind it)?
I'm assuming I shouldn't butt up 2 pieces of trim vertically and would go with a very wide trim (about 8 - 10 inches) to run from the window to the corner but I'm concerned with how that will look.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it less than an inch long? I would keep the window trim and corners consistent throughout the home,although there can be exceptions, but I would strive to keep all details the same, and if it takes short pieces of siding to do so, so be it...

The siding you plan on using can be easy to break at the corners, let alone what a small piece will do. Using a small diameter masonry or glass bit, pilot the hole where the nail will go in. Hardie (r) siding is hung from nails anyway hidden by the next course of siding.

Comment: I've got 8-9 inches to work with so if I use the 3.5 inch trim that leaves me at least an inch for the siding pieces.  I Agree on the need for drilling a pilot hole.  Do you suggest pilot holes in general at the ends of all boards and hand nail rather than pneumatic siding nailer?

Comment: I would try the nail gun for the ends first. The nails are typically made to keep from splitting the wood siding, it may work the same way to keep from cracking the corner off. The last time I set Hardie siding I hand nailed it since it was only a few pieces and one corner broke while I was starting the nail. It broke a small enough corner so it was not below the edge of the next piece, so I let it ride. The head of the nail still held the end. So with that in mind, if the nail gun doesn't push the nails in without cracking, it would be best to pilot as you suggest. A lot of folks would not.